# newcommand with an argument behaves differently from newcommand with no argument

Tags: macros

When I use newcommand with no argument, I get expected behavior.    When I add an argument to my command, latex adds an extra space.    Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\parindent=0 pt
\parskip=12 pt
\newcommand{\mySpace}[1]{\par \vspace{#1pt} \noindent}
\begin{document}
Hullo world. 
\mySpace{1}
Hullo world. 

\renewcommand{\mySpace}{\par \vspace{1pt} \noindent}
Hullo world
\mySpace
Hullo world
\end{document}
```

This code returns the following:

```
Hullo world
 Hullo world
Hullo world
Hullo world
```

I.e., there is an unexpected space at the beginning of the second line.  Is this intended behavior?   If so, I'm curious about why?    How would I restore expected behavior with an argument?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: When there is no argument, the (end-of-line) space following the macro name is absorbed.  With the argument, the (end-of-line) space appears after the right brace, which is not absorbed.  For comparison, with no argument version, nonetheless try `\myspace{}` and you will see the space appear there as well.

Comment: You need to use `%`, as suggested in [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition with argument can use `\ignorespaces` at the end of the definition text to prevent that the following space matters in horizontal mode after `\noindent`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\setlength{\parindent}{0 pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{12 pt}
\newcommand*{\mySpace}[1]{\par \vspace{#1pt} \noindent\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
Hullo world. 
\mySpace{1}
Hullo world. 

\renewcommand{\mySpace}{\par \vspace{1pt} \noindent}
Hullo world
\mySpace
Hullo world
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Case with argument

The original definition:

```
\newcommand{\mySpace}[1]{\par \vspace{#1pt} \noindent}
```

`\par` ends the paragraph, current mode is vertical, where spaces are ignored.
The space after `\par` is already ignored as it ends the command token.
There are two kinds of command token, which start with a backslash:

- Long form, where the name consists of letters (one or more) (`\par`, `\a`, `\vspace`, ...).
- Short form, where the name consists of one non-letter character (`\,`, `\:`, ...).

In the first case, a following space is ignored, in the latter case it is not, because TeX already knows, that the name cannot contain more characters.

The space after `\vspace{#1pt}` becomes a space token, but it is ignored, because TeX is still in vertical mode. The mode is now changed by `\noindent`. Thus the space after `\mySpace{1pt}` matters and it can be seen in the output.

This space is ignored, when `\noindent` is followed by `\ignorespaces`.

BTW: `#1` is expected to be a number, not whole paragraphs, then the argument can be made non-`\long`, which means that TeX complains during the scanning of the argument, if it find empty lines or `\par` tokens. The arguments of a command are made non-`\long`, if the star form of `\newcommand` is used.

### Case without argument

The space after `\mySpace` is ignored as space after a command name, see above.

Comment: Thanks very much for all this helpful information.   I'm happy to use \ignorespaces, but  I inferred from your BTW remark that if I used the star form, i.e., \newcommand*{\mySpace}[1]{\par \vspace{#1pt} \noindent} then the space would be eliminated.    It is not however.  Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @LeoSimon `\ignorespaces` does the trick. The star form is just a convenience, if the closing curly brace after the argument is missing. Then TeX detects this error at the next paragraph and not at the end of the file.